# Trying to use custom DataTemplates inside a ViewRenderer in Xamarin for a UWP control

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am running into an issue with a custom renderer and I am a little stumped/stuck.

I am trying to use the following line of code in a Windows UWP renderer

```
ItemTemplate = (WDataTemplate)WApp.Current.Resources["ItemTemplate"]
```

And I am getting a resource key note found exception and I just do not understand why

The renderer declaration looks like
    public class HorizontalListViewRenderer : ViewRenderer

and the XAML looks like this

```
<control:HorizontalListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <control:HorizontalListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Padding="15,0,15,0">
                 <Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="#323232">
                      <Label.FontSize>
                          <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Android="18" WinPhone="22" iOS="18" />
                      </Label.FontSize>
                 </Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </control:HorizontalListView.ItemTemplate>
</control:HorizontalListView >
```

I have tried on XF2.2 and XF2.3 – both with same issue

Anyone have any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the line

```
ItemTemplate = (WDataTemplate)WApp.Current.Resources["ItemTemplate"]
```

This is referring to the Application.Resources in the UWP app. Go to you App.xaml in your UWP app and then add in the ItemTemplate definition, For example

```
    <Application.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
            <forms:ItemControl HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

Comment: Just FYI this is the exact definition needed for the CarouselView.

Comment: Adam, thanks for the suggestion.  I agree this will work as a possible solution, it is unfortunately not what I am looking for.  I am looking for a why to create a custom control that behaves identical to the out of the box controls.  If not notice, none of the standard controls require the use of Application level resources (FYI this are not very good for performance).  The out of the box controls all support inline ItemTemplate/DataTemplate definitions.

Comment: The other draw back to your suggestion is it limits the control to 1 template for the entire application as it uses effectively a hardcoded name that can only be defined at most once per page.   So what happens if I need 4 or 5 of these controls on a single page with different templates?  In the example you provided, this would not be possible as they would all use the globally defined template.

Comment: Adam if your curious take a look at line 63 here https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WinRT/ListViewRenderer.cs

Comment: I am not sure I understand correctly. The DataTemplate is platform specific and all of UWP standard controls use a single statically defined template. You define you DataTemplate in XF that is different and it is inserted into the data template defined natively.WApp.Current.Resources["ItemTemplate"] gets it from the native app not XF. Also any more info on why its bad for perf, I would be interested to know.

Comment: Partially true :)  DataTemplate is also a Xamarin Forms control that manages a UI layout for controls that support data binding.  Xamarin Forms has a method for allowing each platform to render the Data Template.  I can do it in iOS and Android -- for some reason there is no easy way (at least not documented) to do it on the Windows platform.  Look at any Xamarin Forms Control that supports data binding and you can see they all support what I am looking to do.

Comment: In terms of performance -- all resources at the application level are created at load and remain in memory until the application is unloaded.  By putting a lot of UI based objects there (at least for Windows) can result in a very heavy VisualState tree which is a huge memory hit